# taking file as command line. Visual studio.

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I am trying to run my program but I am not really sure how to do it.

I am working in visual studio and I have to take a file as the command line argument. So this is what I have done.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[] ){


    ifstream inFile( argv[1] );
```

I not sure tho how to call it from the command window in Visual Studio. Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the solution explorer, go to your project and right click it, then choose Properties. On the Debug tab, you can provide arguments.

Comment: You wouldn't type anything with the code you provided. The argument is being provided to the application for you when you debug it. That's the point. If you want to provide different files, you may just want to open the command line in Windows, navigate to your project's bin/debug directory, and type the EXE's name followed by the path to the file you are interested in.